# What BUY order type should I use if I have a limit price in mind, but I still want to capture best price if it goes below my limit?

Tags: equities, trading

I'm pretty new to trading, and I couldn't really find anything helpful online. Say I want to buy a stock for a maximum of 21 USD per share. However, if the price hits 21, I don't want my order to fill instantly and instead want my order to trail down with the price **if** the price keeps going down past 21, and then fills at a price lower than 21 as it bottoms out (say at 20) and starts to come back up to hit my trailing stop. But in the case of it bottoming at exactly 21, I want my order to fill there. Is there some sort of order that I can set up to do this? While we are here, is there a type of SELL order with the same functionality? Where I have a limit price in mind but still let my profits run if they go higher than that price? I don't think a trailing stop limit works because the limit price moves. An adjustable stop order (from limit into a trailing stop) leaves the possibility of buying above my limit price (if I trigger the trailing stop at my limit price).

Thanks so much.

Comment: If the price reaches 21 and then has risen above 21, how could you possibly retroactively fill it at 21?

Comment: @Neel It isn't my intention to retroactively fill it at 21. I imagine that there would be some sort of offset if the price bottoms at 21 and starts to rise, so that my order would fill at 21.05 for example. But in the case of it dropping clearly below 21, I don't want my order to fill at 21 but trail down for a better price.